# How to join the objects of NSMutableArray with a separator in Swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift3

I have got an NSMutableArray declared like as:

```
var operatingDays = NSMutableArray()
```

And next i am appending the objects into the array like this :

```
for operatingDays in forecast.operatingDays! {
              print(operatingDays.days)
              print(operatingDays.times)
              self.operatingDays.add(operatingDays.days)
            }
```

So the operating days array now contains arrays.

[image: Console Output]

Now i want to convert each array to string separated with a space and to show it to the UITableViewCell. For this i am using the code at cellForRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
cell.operationalDays.text = (operatingDays[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).joined(separator: " ")
```

But it shows the error :

[image]

Comment: Cast to [String] instead of AnyObject, your array is an array of arrays?

Comment: @ReinierMelian does String have a method named `joined`?

Comment: yes of course it is

Comment: check my comment again, was edited @mag_zbc

Comment: @ChelseaShawra let me know if works

Comment: Sorry it is not working... Still it shows "string"has no member joined

Comment: @ChelseaShawra check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my first comment, casting your `operatingDays[indexPath.row]` to `[String]` it works, Try with this

```
if let arrayOfStrings = operatingDays[indexPath.row] as? [String]
{
  cell.operationalDays.text = arrayOfStrings.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Solution is below:

```
var operatingDays = [Any]()
cell.operationalDays.text = (operatingDays[indexPath.row] as? [String])?.joined(separator: " ")
```

or

```
if let data = operatingDays[indexPath.row] as? [String] {
     cell.operationalDays.text = data.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to joint array as below:

```
let tempArr = operatingDays[indexPath.row] as! NSArray
cell.operationalDays.text = tempArr.componentsJoined(by: " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast AnyObject to Array to use joined function.

```
if let isArray = operatingDays[indexPath.row] as? [String] {
    //Now you can able to use joined function
    cell.operationalDays.text = isArray.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

Comment: May i know the reason for down voting? is anything wrong let me know i will update myself.No use of down voting without commenting.Thanks